# why setInterval() cycle goes faster every time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm building a custom slider on Javascript , and I want that every time the user clicks on a div of the slider, the slider should stop for X seconds.

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ciclo;
    var index_slide = 1;

    function startSlidercicle() {
        ciclo = setInterval( function() {
            // Slider code goes here
        }, 3000); 
    }

    //Here I start the slider animation
    startSlidercicle();

    //When the user clicks on a div called 'slide', stop the cycle and start again the animation cycle
    $('.slide').on('click', function() {
        clearInterval(ciclo);
        setTimeout(startSlidercicle(), 3000);
    });
});
```

But the problem is that everytime I click and stop the slider, the cycle starts faster and faster. How can I fix it?

Comment: You should be using `setTimeout(startSlidercicle, 3000)` (no parentheses after `startSlidercicle`). But that shouldn't be causing what you describe...

Comment: I can only reproduce that if I click the .slide div multiple times (see http://jsfiddle.net/XdMHz/). You should add a guard against that, because it creates "leftover" timers you can't reference/clear.

Comment: I've read some questions about the same topic, but I don't have clear how to prevent or close those multiple timers

Comment: One way that you can prevent the multiple timers is basically the same way you currently clear your interval: create a new variable `timerId` (or whatever you want to call it) then in your click handler add `clearTimeout(timerId)` and then `timerId = setTimeout(...`.

Comment: There is no other setTimeout or setInterval in the missing slider code? Can't seem to recreate the issue with what you've got here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of:

```
clearInterval(ciclo);
setTimeout(startSlidercicle(), 3000);
```

or:

```
clearInterval(ciclo);
setTimeout(startSlidercicle, 3000);
```

I changed the code to be:

```
clearInterval(ciclo);
startSlidercicle();
```

And now the slider just works fine. I think that, in the first two proposals, every time I click on the div, a new function is created, "overlapping" over the existing cycle and, thus, it looks like the slider speeds up, but its just one cycle starting over another.

Comment: Already tested with Firefox 23, IE 9, Opera 12+ and Chrome 29 on Windows 7 and still works fine.

Comment: My conclusion is that `clearInterval(ciclo)` ends the `setInterval` cycle inside `startSlidercicle()`, so, there is no remaining code inside the function and exits, then jumps to the next line where I call a new `startSlidercicle()`, and if I click many times, I'm just finishing and starting new `setInterval` methods

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this:

```
clearInterval(ciclo);
setTimeout(startSlidercicle(), 3000);
```

to this:

```
clearInterval(ciclo);
setTimeout(startSlidercicle, 3000);
```

In your existing code, you are calling `startSlidercirle` immediately and it is not waiting until the `setTimeout()` fires because you have the `()` after the function name.  That means to execute it immediately and pass the result of executing that to `setTimeout()`.  You want to just pass the function reference to `setTimeout()` which is done by just having the name of the function with no `()` after it.  This is a common mistake.